# When i was run react, then it's give me this error? I can't understood what's problem it is. Now, what can i do?

Tags: reactjs

smhemel at MacBook-Air in ~/Desktop/CODE.....!!!!/React/First Project/preject_1 on master*

> $ npm start
>
> preject_1@0.1.0 start /Users/smhemel/Desktop/CODE.....!!!!/React/First Project/preject_1
>   react-scripts start

Failed to compile.

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be one of these:

```
RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? } | [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
```

-> One or multiple rule conditions
   Details:

- configuration.module.rules[1].include should be an instance of RegExp
- configuration.module.rules[1].include: The provided value "/Users/smhemel/Desktop/CODE.....!!!!/React/First Project/preject_1/src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
- configuration.module.rules[1].include should be an instance of function
- configuration.module.rules[1].include should be an array:
  [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
- configuration.module.rules[1].include should be an object.
- configuration.module.rules[1].include should be an array:
  [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be an instance of RegExp
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include: The provided value "/Users/smhemel/Desktop/CODE.....!!!!/React/First Project/preject_1/src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be an instance of function
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be an array:
  [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be an object.
- configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include should be an array:
  [RegExp | string | function | [(recursive)] | object { and?, exclude?, include?, not?, or?, test? }]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! preject_1@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the preject_1@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. 
There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! /Users/smhemel/.npm/_logs/2019-03-04T07_04_28_650Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you name your folder `/Users/smhemel/Desktop/CODE.....!!!!`?

Comment: The error message is fairly clear: you cannot have exclamation marks in your path, or you'll have to figure out how to escape them